# Variable will not change

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, pygame

My program is working fine (without errors) but it doesn't change one variable (`limit`). Why and how do I solve that problem?

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,600))
```

---

```
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
```

---

```
o = 450 #second circle y
```

---

```
ticket5 = True
limit = 475
```

---

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            False
            pygame.quit()

    screen.fill(white)
```

---

```
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, green, (800, o), 75)
    if o == limit:
        ticket5 = True
        limit -= 25
    elif o == 550:
        ticket5 = False
    if ticket == True:
        o += 1
    else:
        o-= 1
```

Comment: Could you display the declaration of the limit variable, to see if its a read only.

Comment: Are you changing `limit` in a function?

Comment: @TheodorSolbjørg this is python, there's no such thing as variable declaration or read-only identifiers. @OP, probably the condition for changing `limit` is never fulfilled - try adding print statements to the if/elif blocks to see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using a variable called `ticket5` which starts with a value of True.

You are later checking `if ticket == True` maybe that should be `if ticket5 == True`

Otherwise `o += 1` will never be hit and the variable `o` will never grow. And if `o` never grows then `o == limit` will never be True and `limit` will never be changed.